# Optimising away function table in C(++)

Tags: c++, c, optimization

In order to make a section of a programme easy to unit test I would like to make it take a table of functions which can either point to operating system primitives (i.e. a function to report that we can offer a set of clipboard targets) or to test versions.  Ideally though I would not like to have the overhead of a function table in the live version, just the additional structure it lends to the code.  So I would like some way to tell the compiler that the function table will never change, so that it can optimise away the look-ups.  Something like this (simple-minded implementation for illustration):

```
#ifndef TEST
const
#endif
static struct {
    void (*reportTargets)(size_t targetc, const char **targetv);
    [...]
} interfaceToOutside
#ifndef TEST
= {
    reportTargetsLive,
    [...]
}
#endif
;
```

Is this likely to do the trick, and if not any good suggestions about how to achieve this (or do it better)?

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's the latter, then you're basically describing virtual functions, which the compiler is usually pretty good at optimising...

Comment: I don't think it is worth bothering, and I am not sure that the compiler will always optimize the call to avoid indirection (and that probably does not matter in practice).

Comment: Oli, I would have thought that the semantics of virtual functions actually prevented the compiler from fully optimising away the look-up (for example inlining if the function was a suitable candidate).  Edit: that said, I could always #ifdef the virtual keyword.  Basile, I realise that the gains will normally be minimal, I am asking as much from interest as for practical value.

Comment: I'd not bother `#ifdef`ing anything out (unless a profiler tells me to). On the contrary, I'd use an interface vith virtual functions for the needed OS functionality and provide implementations for the OS you are developing on and for the unit tests. This makes the code cleaner and better maintainable than `#ifdef`d handwritten vtables. It provides a clean separation of concerns of the code using the clipborad service from that service's implementation. And as a bonus, it facilitates later ports to other OSes, where you just might provide another implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

> So I would like some way to tell the compiler that the function table will never change (...)

Well, declare all `const` (BTW, you should rather interleave the first `const` between `static` and `struct`):

```
#ifndef TEST
# define CONST const
#else
# define CONST 
#endif

static CONST struct {
    void (*CONST reportTargets)(size_t targetc, const char **targetv);
    [...]
} interfaceToOutside
#ifndef TEST
= {
    reportTargetsLive,
    [...]
}
#endif
;

#undef CONST
```

(the macro name is bad, I know).

Now,

> Is this likely to do the trick (...)?

I think so, but you should still check the generated assembler code (`-S` option for `gcc`/`g++`).

Answer (score 0):

instead of function pointers, you can make 2 structs with static inline functions. One is for test, the other is for real. Now, depending on how you instantiate the template, you are either in test mode or in live mode.

```
struct Live
{
    static void Report(const std::string& report) { ReportLive(report); }
};

struct Test
{
    static void Report(const std::string& report) { ReportTest(report); }
};

template<typename T>
class Reporter
{
public:
    void doReport()
    {
        //some stuff todo
        T::Report(report);
        //other stuff todo
    }
};
```

This just as an idea. The compiler will optimize the struct away (fully) when inlining the code. Additionally, you can select different testing behavior by implementing different structs.